# Renaming the field label from "author" to "created by"

Tags: theming

How can I implement a hook in my template file that will change the label of a field for the "group" content type from "author" to "created by"?

[image: screenshot of author field]

Comment: Are you using drupal 6 or drupal 7. Did you create this field for the "group" content type. Or is this specific to a module you are using. Please provide more  information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To rename the label of a field add the preprocess function [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) to your *template.php* file:

```
function *YOUR THEME*_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  //Supposing that your content type name is "group"
  if($vars['type'] == 'group'){
    //Supposing that your field name is "field_txt_group"
    $vars['content']['field_txt_author']['#title'] = 'created by';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess that there are a few different ways you can do this.

1. Use jQuery to target the element and use text replacement. You could so something like:

   ```
   $("#my-element").each(function () { 
     var s=$(this).text(); //get text
     $(this).text(s.replace('Author', 'created by')); //set the text to the replaced version
   });
   ```

Of course you will need to add on Drupal specific jQuery code depending on what version of Drupal you are using (6 or 7). See: [JavaScript in Drupal 5 and Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/121997) and [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722).

1. Try the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module
2. Write a template pre-process function (template.php in your theme folder) to replace that text.

Comment: String Overrides would surely affect any usage of the word "author" which is probably not what's wanted here. jQuery is not an ideal way of changing this. The best approach would be to investigate some preprocess functions and change it only for the required content types.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the label from a field preprocess

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) { 
  $field_name = $variables['element']['#field_name'];  
  $view_mode = $variables['element']['#view_mode'];

  switch ($field_name) {
    case 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME':
      $variables['label'] = t('FIELD LABEL EVERYWHERE');
      // Possible to restrict by view mode
      if ($view_mode == 'teaser') {
        $variables['label'] = t('TEASER LABEL HERE');
      }
      break;

    // Duplicate for other fields
    case 'OTHER_FIELD_MACHINE_NAMES':
      // ...code
      break;
  }

}
```