# How to make labels of fields selectable?

Tags: nodes, entities

Does anybody know if there is a module to make labels of fields selectable,
for instance 
Field course:

- Abc in DCT
- 123 today
- listening pop

so if I select 123 today, in my content display I would have:

**course:** 123 today

but I would like to change **course:** by **workshop:** at the visualization of the content and have "course" for the other two (Abc in DCT and listening pop). So maybe there is a module that allows label selection, I haven't find it yet.

Comment: By the way, I'm on D7

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a custom field formatter with a settings form where you select the label and then output it accordingly.

Like in this [tutorial about field formatters](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do not get wrongly, this offers an alternate label, what I need is a list of lables to choose, and this available at the moment of content cretion, so if the content creator has to add in the courses field a course, he should be able to label it either course or workshop...

Comment: This is also possible, you'll just have to add the list as a part of the field input. Probably by adding an entire new custom field type.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of modules you can try:

- [Field Display Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_display_label) seems pretty simple, but it may be exactly what you need.
- [Field Formatter Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_label) looks similar but has less users and no stable release.
- [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) can do this as you can see in [this tutorial](http://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-display-suite-field-settings/), but it also does a lot more than that so it might be overkill for your use case.

Besides these modules, you can do it in code using custom formatters like [Suranga said](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/159217/226) or [implementing theme preprocessors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19125/renaming-the-field-label-from-author-to-created-by).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but these modules offer an alternate label, what I need is a list of lables to choose, and this available at the moment of content cretion, so if the content creator has to add in the courses field a course, he should be able to label it either course or workshop...

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is actually two fields. One is the "label" (a textfield limited to a select number of otpions, or a taxonomy term), the other is the description.

You can do this a bunch of different ways, depending on your needs:

- Entity References (allows multiple)
- Field Collections (allows multiple)
- Field Groups/Fieldsets (only one)

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to click on the description and the label will automatically show up. To do that, I would predefine the labels and descriptions by creating them in a separate entity. Then, you could select these from a list of descriptions by using the Entity Reference module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I started to look for a how to, do you have any link already to a how-to, it is just that I'm not an expert, sorry.